# WPF Binding Int32 Value to Duration Property (DataTime.Seconds)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I want to visualize a cool-down timer using a ProgressBar and I thought of solving it by using a StoryBoard and each time my DataContext refreshes it should trigger an animation (cooling down).

I'm wondering if there is a way to bind a Property, which is an `Int32` value actually to a `Duration` property of an animation.

The Duration property represents a DateTime value. I need to bind the integer value as the seconds of the duration. Is there a way without converting the Int into DateTime? If there are any other suggestions of realizing the cool-down thing i'm glad to hear about it!

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="timeToUpdateBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" From="100" To="0" Duration="{Binding myDataContext.myIntValueInSeconds}" RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Use an appropriate [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without converter, impossible.